# Update column in pandas dataframe based on another column of the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am struggling with updating a dataframe columns. Here is a sample of my dataframe :

```
data1={'UserId': [1, 2, 3], 'OldAnswer': [4, 4, None]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1)

data2={'UserId': [1, 2, 3], 'NewAnswer' : [4, 5, None]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)

merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on ='UserId', how='outer')
```

Which gives me :

| UserId | OldAnswer | NewAnswer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | NaN | NaN |

Now I Want to update the "OldAnswer" with the "NewAnswer" on rows but when I check the difference between the two columns, it says that on the third row, OldAnswer and NewAnswer are differents. The following code gives me the following result :

```
merged['OldAnswer'] != merged['NewAnswer']

 > False
 > True    
 > True
```

I thought I would have been able to update my column by doing this :

```
i = 0
while i < len(merged):
    if merged['OldAnswer'].iloc[i] != merged['NewAnswer'].iloc[i]:
        merged['OldAnswer'].iloc[i] = merged['NewAnswer'].iloc[i]
        i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

But it doesn't work either.

Comment: Afterwards your "OldAnswer" column is going to look like the "NewAnswer" column, right?

Comment: What is the expected result? And why does it matters whether the values are different before if they just have to be the same after?

Comment: Yes indeed... I feel a bit dumb right now! 
merged['OldAnswer'] = merged['NewAnswer'] solved it

Answer (score 0):

I feel a bit dumb right now! The simple following code solved it:

```
merged['OldAnswer'] = merged['NewAnswer']
merged.drop(columns='NewAnswer')
```